# How to ensure that vectors have the same width (equation)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, vector

I'm making 4 vectors of length 8 with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} \newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\newcommand{\powerset}{\raisebox{.15\baselineskip}{\Large\ensuremath{\wp}}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\title{ Groupwork}
\author{some names}
\date{June 2018}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Exercise 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item
%some text here 
Mathijs's: $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}$, Abdul: $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 
0 \end{bmatrix}$, Oleksandr: $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 
2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$, Laurens: $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 
-2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The problem is demonstrated in the screenshot[image], namely that the size of Mathijs's vectors is clearly smaller/different than the rest and that's because he doesn't have any negative numbers in his vector. I would still like to have that vector to have the same size as the rest. How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may work with `\hphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} \newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\newcommand{\powerset}{\raisebox{.15\baselineskip}{\Large\ensuremath{\wp}}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\title{ Groupwork}
\author{some names}
\date{June 2018}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Exercise 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item
%some text here 
Mathijs's: $\begin{bmatrix}\hphantom{-2}\makebox[0pt][r]{2\;\,} \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}$, Abdul: $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 
0 \end{bmatrix}$, Oleksandr: $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 
2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$, Laurens: $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 
-2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But personally I would not do that.

Comment: Why not and how would you get around this?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji This is really just personal taste. I see why you want to make things uniform, but then there is the point that this "wastes" some space. So it depends on your preferences what you value higher.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\newcommand{\powerset}{{\mathpalette\myraise\wp}}
\newcommand{\myraise}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.4}{$#1#2$}}}%
}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}

\newcommand{\adjwd}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$#1$}]{#2}}

\title{Groupwork}
\author{some names}
\date{June 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Exercise 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item
%some text here 
Mathijs's:
  $\begin{bmatrix}\adjwd{-2}{2} \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
Abdul:
  $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
Oleksandr:
  $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$,
Laurens: $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

\item Power set $\powerset(X)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I also suggest a better way to typeset the power set symbol (although I wouldn't use Weierstrass’ p for the purpose).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, with the small `makebox` package. In addition, a variant  with medium-sized matrices, which look better, in my opinion, for matrices with many rows and  not so many columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut, makebox}
\newenvironment{mbmatrix}[1][c]{\medsize\begin{bmatrix*}[#1]\bigstrut[t]}{\end{bmatrix*}\endmedsize}

\title{ Groupwork}
\author{some names}
\date{June 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Exercise 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item
%some text here
Mathijs's: $\begin{bmatrix}\makebox*{$-2$}{$ 2 $} \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$, Abdul: $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\
0 \end{bmatrix}$, Oleksandr: $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\\ -2 \\ 0 \\
2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$, Laurens: $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
-2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$\medskip
%
\item
%%some text here
Mathijs's: $\begin{mbmatrix}\makebox*{$-2$}{$ 2 $} \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{mbmatrix}$, Abdul: $\begin{mbmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\
0 \end{mbmatrix}$, Oleksandr: $\begin{mbmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\\ -2 \\ 0 \\
2 \\ 2 \end{mbmatrix}$, Laurens: $ \begin{mbmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
-2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{mbmatrix}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]